# Move rectangle in response to keypress?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Is there any way to make the if statement that checks if the 'd' key is pressed to work?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void player(SDL_Renderer* renderer) {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.w = 50;
    rect.h = 50;
    rect.x = 600 - (rect.w / 2);
    rect.y = 325 - (rect.h / 2);
    SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &rect);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == 'd') {
                rect.x += 10;
            }
        }
    }
}

void runwindow(int width, int height) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Top Down Shooter", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    
    //initialize stuff
    player(renderer);

    //quit
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event e;

    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
        
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    runwindow(1200, 650);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Additional information:

1. Using Visual Studio 2022
2. Using SDL2

Comment: What exactly doesn't work??

Comment: How do you expect the program to do anything once it's in the `while (!quit)` loop?

Comment: https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guideinputkeyboard.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you usually must have a single main loop in the entire program. This loop:

```
while (!quit) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            quit = true;
        }
    }

    // <---
}
```

And all your logic and rendering should happen somewhere in this loop, at the `// <--`.

Remove that other loop from `player()` (I just removed the whole function for now).

Something like this would work inside of the loop:

```
// Update.

if (SDL_GetKeyboardState(nullptr)[SDL_SCANCODE_D])
    player_x += 3;

// Draw.

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

SDL_Rect rect;
rect.w = 50;
rect.h = 50;
rect.x = width / 2 - rect.w / 2 + player_x;
rect.y = height / 2 - rect.h;
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &rect);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

Where `player_x` is a variable that persists between the loop iterations (`int player_x = 0;` declared right before `while (!quit) {`).

---

You also need to limit how many times per second `player_x += 3;` happens, otherwise the square will get off-screen instantly. The famous article on doing that is [Fix your timestep!](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/). The minimal sane example looks like this:

Outside of the loop:

```
std::uint64_t tick_duration = SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency() / 60;
std::uint64_t starting_time = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
std::uint64_t accumulated_time = 0;
```

Inside the loop:

```
// Update.

std::uint64_t current_time = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
if (current_time > starting_time)
    accumulated_time += current_time - starting_time;
starting_time = current_time;

while (accumulated_time > tick_duration)
{
    accumulated_time -= tick_duration;
    if (SDL_GetKeyboardState(nullptr)[SDL_SCANCODE_D])
        player_x += 3;
}
```

`SDL_GetPerformanceCounter()` returns a number that's continuously incremented. The frequency at which it's incremented is `SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency()` times per second.

Here, `while (accumulated_time > tick_duration)` will end up executing 60 times per second on average (because we did `tick_duration = SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency() / 60`).

---

You also should limit your FPS to avoid heating up your machine for no good reason. Pass `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC` as the last argument to `SDL_CreateRenderer()` instead of `0`.

---

Also get rid of `<conio.h>`. You don't use it, and it only exists on Windows. I had to remove it to compile on Linux.

---

I've used `SDL_GetKeyboardState()` to determine whether a key is pressed. If you want to, you can do that manually in the event loop (like you attempted to do). Something like this:

Outside the loop: `bool d_pressed = false;`.

Replace your `SDL_PollEvent()` loop with this:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
    switch (e.type)
    {
      case SDL_QUIT:
        quit = true;
        break;
      case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        if (e.key.keysym.scancode == SDL_SCANCODE_D)
            d_pressed = true;
        break;
      case SDL_KEYUP:
        if (e.key.keysym.scancode == SDL_SCANCODE_D)
            d_pressed = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

And replace `if (SDL_GetKeyboardState(nullptr)[SDL_SCANCODE_D])` with `if (d_pressed)`.

Notice that I'm using `e.key.keysym.scancode == SDL_SCANCODE_D` instead of `e.key.keysym.sym == 'd'`. Both methods appear to work on the surface, but game controls should always use the former, otherwise players with unusual keyboard layouts (AZERTY) will hate you (scancodes represent physical key positions, so WASD scancodes will automatically get remapped to ZQSD on AZERTY keyboards, which is a good thing; keycodes won't get remapped).

---

Also it's a good idea to check the return values of various initialization functions for errors.

---

Here's the complete code I ended up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

void runwindow(int width, int height) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Top Down Shooter", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    //quit
    bool quit = false;

    int player_x = 0;

    std::uint64_t tick_duration = SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency() / 60;
    std::uint64_t starting_time = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
    std::uint64_t accumulated_time = 0;
    bool d_pressed = false;

    while (!quit) {
        SDL_Event e;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
            switch (e.type)
            {
              case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = true;
                break;
              case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                if (e.key.keysym.scancode == SDL_SCANCODE_D)
                    d_pressed = true;
                break;
              case SDL_KEYUP:
                if (e.key.keysym.scancode == SDL_SCANCODE_D)
                    d_pressed = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Update.

        std::uint64_t current_time = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
        if (current_time > starting_time)
            accumulated_time += current_time - starting_time;
        starting_time = current_time;

        while (accumulated_time > tick_duration)
        {
            accumulated_time -= tick_duration;
            if (d_pressed)
                player_x += 3;
        }

        // Draw.

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_Rect rect;
        rect.w = 50;
        rect.h = 50;
        rect.x = width / 2 - rect.w / 2 + player_x;
        rect.y = height / 2 - rect.h;
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &rect);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int, char**) {
    runwindow(1200, 650);
    return 0;
}
```